# Default values not going through my Angular Form

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

Im using an Angular template form and I have some values that should be set by default by me using the value property of the input tag.  None of the default values are making it through currently.

```
<form #npcCreateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createNpc(npcCreateForm)">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" ngModel>
<label for="race">Race</label>
<input type="text" name="race" ngModel>
<label for="characterClass">Class</label>
<input type="text" name="characterClass" ngModel>
<label for="level">Level</label>
<input type="number" name="level" ngModel max="20" min="1" value="1">
```

I cut the form short, because I have several properties that repeat like the final one.  I want to also detail that I am able to retrieve any inputted data, so that isn't an issue. 
Here is what grabbing the data looks like from the component:

```
createNpc(createForm: NgForm) {
  let formValue = createForm.value;
  console.log(formValue);
  let createdNpc: Npc = new Npc(formValue.name, formValue.race, formValue.characterClass, formValue.level, formValue.strength, formValue.dexterity, formValue.constitution, formValue.intelligence, formValue.wisdom, formValue.charisma, formValue.difficultyLevel);
  console.log(createdNpc);
  createdNpc.equipmentList = this.localEquipmentList;
  this.dataService.addNpc(createdNpc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your information (without knowing your Angular version and other stuff), here is how to bind a input with a ngModel correctly with a form:

```
<form #npcCreateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createNpc()">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
</form>
```

In your component it looks like this:

```
name: string;

createNpc() {
     console.log(this.name);
}
```

If you wanna do it through your form you need [@ViewChild](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/):

```
@ViewChild('npcCreateForm') npcCreateForm: FormGroupDirective;

createNpc() {
    const formGroup: FormGroup = npcCreateForm.form;
    // this.formGroup.controls['name']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer CodeNashor, I'm using Angular4 and his solution was close.  I tried using [(ngModel)] but I got a giant list of errors, and so I tried just ngModel="value" and that seems to have worked.